# why is checkbox.click() not working for me?

Tags: checkbox, click, protractor

I need to click on a checkbox that is checked by default. Here is my element:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="filterMethods" id="filterMethods" ng-model="globalFilters.methods" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty" style="">
```

When I manually uncheck the checkbox the ng-not-empty changes to ng-empty.

This is how I am trying to uncheck this checkbox:

```
    element(by.css('input[name=filterMethods]')).click();
```

This is not showing any error but the element is not getting unchecked. Can someone suggest how can I get it working? I have six such checkboxes in that block. I need to check and uncheck each of them to test the filter function. Please suggest the optimal way to achieve the same.

Comment: use change event and check if your checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around the attributes value.  Try this:
`element(by.css('input[name="filterMethods"]')).click();`

But I'm not sure why you wouldnt use Id in this case, since you have it.

`element(by.css('#filterMethods')).click();`

Or you can even use the model:
`element(by.model('globalFilters.methods')).click();`

Comment: thanks. The quotes around the attribute value did the trick, it works now with the quotes.

Comment: @SandhyaC cool.  please consider marking answer as correct to help others

Comment: I am new to SO and am not really sure how to mark the answer as correct. Can you guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your test is performing faster than the tested code. Have you tried with a promise?

```
element(by.css('input[name=filterMethods]')).then(function(arg){
   arg.click()
});
```

Or you can try to wait some time:

```
browser.sleep(35000).then(function(){
 element(by.css('input[name=filterMethods]')).then(function(arg){
   arg.click()
 })
})
```